# How to split a list using two nested conditions

Tags: python, list

Basically I have list of `0`s and `1`s. Each value in the list represents a data sample from an hour. Thus, if there are 24 `0`s and `1`s in the list that means there are 24 hours, or a single day. I want to capture the first time the data cycles from `0`s to `1`s back to `0`s in a span of 24 hours (or vice versa from `1`s to `0`s back to `1`s).

```py
signal = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

expected output:

```py
#                                                     D   
signal = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]
output = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
#                           ^ cycle.1:day.1           |dayline        ^cycle.1:day.2
```

In the output list, when there is 1 that means 1 cycle is completed at that position of the signal list and at rest of the position there are 0. There should only 1 cycle in a days that's why only 1 is there.

I don't how to split this list according to that so can someone please help?

Comment: why there is o instead of 0? also can you explain how output list has only 2 ones?

Comment: I have edited my question and 1 basicially represent that at that position cycle is completed .

Comment: I think you must elaborate how you got only two 1s in the output list, because it is unclear from the explanation you have given.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams to me like what you are trying to do is split your data first into blocks of 24, and then to find either the first rising edge, or the first falling edge depending on the first hour in that block.

Below I have tried to distill my understanding of what you are trying to accomplish into the following function. It takes in a `numpy.array` containing zeros and ones, as in your example. It checks to see what the first hour in the day is, and decides what type of edge to look for.
it detects an edge by using `np.diff`. This gives us an array containing `-1`'s, `0`'s, and `1`'s. We then look for the first index of either a `-1` falling edge, or `1` rising edge. The function returns that index, or if no edges were found it returns the index of the last element, or nothing.

For more info see the docs for descriptions on numpy features used here [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), [`np.array.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), [`np.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html)

```py
import numpy as np

def get_cycle_index(day):
    '''
    returns the first index of a cycle defined by nipun vats
    if no cycle is found returns nothing
    '''

    first_hour = day[0]
    if first_hour == 0:
        edgetype = -1
    else:
        edgetype = 1

    edges = np.diff(np.r_[day, day[-1]])

    if (edges == edgetype).any():
        return (edges == edgetype).nonzero()[0][0]
    elif (day.sum() == day.size) or day.sum() == 0:
        return
    else:
        return day.size - 1
```

Below is an example of how you might use this function in your case.

```py
import numpy as np

_data = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
#_data = np.random.randint(0,2,280, dtype='int')
data = np.array(_data, 'int')

#split the data into a set of 'day' blocks
blocks = np.array_split(data, np.arange(24,data.size, 24))


_output = []

for i, day in enumerate(blocks):
    print(f'day {i}')
    buffer = np.zeros(day.size, dtype='int')
    print('\tsignal:', *day, sep = ' ')
    cycle_index = get_cycle_index(day)
    if cycle_index:
        buffer[cycle_index] = 1
    print('\toutput:', *buffer, sep=' ')

    _output.append(buffer)

output = np.concatenate(_output)
print('\nfinal output:\n', *output, sep=' ')
```

this yeilds the following output:

```
day 0
    signal: 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
    output: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
day 1
    signal: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    output: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
day 2
    signal: 0 0 0 0 0 0
    output: 0 0 0 0 0 0

final output:
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: that's right that I wan to split the list into 24 blocks but after that, I want to find a particular cycle in it. Cycle can be of 0s and 1s or 1s and 0s. And in one set of 24 blocks, there can be only 1 cycle. Cycle example in the list: one cycle = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 ]. That's it here first cycle is completed\

Comment: In a cycle, there can be only one continuous 1s and one continuous 0s and that's it for that particular set of 24 blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. But it seams like we aren't to far off, once you split the data into 24 hr blocks, you can look for any pattern you want in that block. 

Is it the case that [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0] is a cycle and in the output you expect [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]?

Comment: yes, the output basically represents the position of the cycle at which it gets completed. So here at 9th position of the signal list, the cycle is completed, so I print 1 at 9th position

Comment: Ok, so in the case of [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1] you would want output to be [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]. And do you want a cycle detected in this case: [0,0,0,0]? Or in this case [1,1,1,1]?

Comment: No, 1 should be at the end of the consecutive number(either 0 or 1). So ans will be [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0].

Comment: And no that would not be a cycle if only 0s are there or 1s are there.

Comment: 1 cycle is the main cycle of 24 blocks as you know and 1 cycle is of continuous consecutive 0s and1s. for example of Cycles: [1,1,1,0,0,0] , [0,0,0,1,1,1] , [1,0] , [0,1] and non cycles: [1,1,1] , [0,0,0] ,[1] , [0].

Comment: Okay, I think I'm getting the idea, the logic for that is going to be a little more tricky you need to check for two things exclusivley and then compare the conditions with an OR. There is probably an elegant way to do it, and the best I could come up with would be a stack of conditional statements. I will edit my answer shortly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214816/discussion-between-andrew-micalled-and-nipun-vats).

Comment: Okay, I edited my amswer in line with our discussion above. If that solves your problem it'd be great if you would accept the answer.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer again. This time cleaning up the logic and encapsulating it in a function that can be edited seperatley. If we are still getting an off by 1 error then it should just be a matter of adding 1 to the functions output.